# Is "the" required in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> There is no serious work on this subject. The existing literature
>   lacks **the** proper focus.

Is "the" required before "proper focus"? Why?

Comment: It's not required, but neither is it wrong.

Comment: @JasonBassford If it is not required, then is it more idiomatic not to use it?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. There is no way I could guess which is *better* here. Both with and without the article, the sentence seems perfectly normal to me. Perhaps including the article makes it more formal—so that context might determine something.

Comment: @JasonBassford There should be a way to find out which is preferable.

Comment: There almost certainly is not. Even Google Ngram Viewer, which is only for writing, would struggle with a five-word expression that applied to every situation in which the article could or could not be used. You could poll everybody in the world and come up with a consensus. But what if 55% preferred it one way and 45% the other? Simply knowing that difference in number wouldn't tell you anything necessarily relevant. Why does *anyone* use one word over another? People even change the specific words they use from one day to the next. This particular case is like that.